# sending an array to javascript through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to send an array from PHP to Ajax in javascript. 
my array in PHP file "myphp.php" is $parts and is multidimentional.

I have used both echo $parts and echo json_encode($parts) none works for me.
$parts has 2 rows and 2 columns this is the result of var_dump:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "1350655763.12" [1]=> string(2) "25" [2]=> string(1) " " } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "1350655763.12" [1]=> string(2) "26" [2]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

I want to send the hole array to Ajax but just display $parts[0][0] on the web page.
When I use

```
echo $parts
```

in myphp.php file: "Array" name is displayed on the web page
When I use

```
echo json_encode($parts)
```

in myphp.php file: all components of the array are displayed instead of the first one

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
function getXMLHttp()
{
  var xmlHttp

  try
  {
    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    //Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest()
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
     { 
      var parts=JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); 
      document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = parts[0][0]; 
     }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "myphp.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}


result=MakeRequest();



</script>


  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='ResponseDiv'>
      This is a div to hold the response.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How should I change these codes to just get parst[0][0] on the webpage?
Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html) on at javascript and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) at php.

PHP:

```
$parts = array();
....
echo (json_encode($parts));
```

Javascript:

```
var parts = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Optionally, on your PHP page, you can also define `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: which part of code in javascript I need to change?  I used var parts = JSON.Parse(result) and then document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = parts[0][0]    I does not work !

Comment: the part where you are getting response from the ajax. In your code, its `HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);` line. Replace this line by  `var parts = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);alert(parts);` and rest you can understand OR can ask me again here.

Comment: I changed it to "HandleResponse(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));" but it does not work even now

Comment: Please remove the HandleResponse. I don't know where have you declared that function. Just replace `HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);` by `var parts=JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);alert(parts[0][0]);`

Comment: I changed one part of code  as you said but still does not work  (I put that part betwen stars //*** so you can find)   could you please take a look at that part

Comment: My God... your PHP page name is `myphp.php` and you are calling `ajax.php`. how can this work? Please replace line 51 with `xmlHttp.open("GET", "myphp.php", true);`

Comment: sorry in my computer its name is Ajax.php here I wrote it as myphp.php but still nope do not work!?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18494/discussion-between-dhairya-vora-and-reza-asgharzadeh)

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your json encoded data into javascript before use it.
Please check json here

http://www.json.org/js.html

Please try this code:

```
result = MakeRequest();
var myObject = eval('(' + result + ')');
alert(myObject[0][0]);
```